# Authentication error in Node.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to make a WebAPI call from server script and i am getting authentication error:

This is how my server.js looks like:

```
var app = require('http').createServer()
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')
  , moment = require('moment')
  , request = require('request'); //https://github.com/mikeal/request

app.listen(8000, function () {
    console.log('server started');
    doSomethingOnServerStart();
});


function doSomethingOnServerStart()
{
    console.log('Getting something from server');

    request.get({
        url: 'http://localhost:63213/Api/MyAPI/GetSomething',

    },
        function (error, response, body) {
            console.log(response.statusCode);
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {

                console.log('data received from server');

            } else {
                console.log('error: ' + response.statusCode);
                console.log(body);
            }
        });

}
```

I am using Mikeal's Request library to make the WebAPI call. In the HTTP Authentication section (https://github.com/mikeal/request#http-authentication), it says pass username and password as "hash" but does not say how do i generate that hash.

I am kind of stuck and dont know how to proceed.

Comment: Could you make that second question an actual question. Then I'll move my answer to that question so you can accept it if it is to your liking. Let's keep questions and posts at a one-to-one on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: @kentcdodds : thanks for your response. here is the link to the separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558409/how-do-i-avoid-stroing-username-password-when-using-request-module-with-node-js

Comment: I hope that my answers have helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your initial question, judging from [the documentation](https://github.com/mikeal/request#http-authentication) it looks like you need to make an additional chained function call:

```
request.get('http://some.server.com/').auth('username', 'password', false);
```

or like this

```
request.get('http://some.server.com/', {
  'auth': {
    'user': 'username',
    'pass': 'password',
    'sendImmediately': false
  }
});
```

In the second case it mentions having to have `auth` as a hash (as it is above). It doesn't appear you're sending a username or password anywhere in your code...